# Ubuntu 20.04 upgrade is not running after restart - suspect power failure during upgrade

Tags: upgrade

While I was upgrading to 20.04 from 18.04 LTS power went off. However I continued after switching main power supply. The upgrading continued and I noticed some changes in desktop like some new icons. However after restarting I see only a lot of coding lines. The login screen doesn't show up. In the lines I see two lines which says Failed- 1) Failed to listen on udev Kernel socket. 2) Failed to listen on udev control socket.
Please help. I didn't take a backup for an external device. But I always notice the notification that 'back up is saved' probably in the system itself. Machine Lenovo.
Thanks friends.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Solved it this way:

1. Created a Bootable USB using my windows partition/another computer
2. Booted the computer via the USB
3. Logged into the root of the computer via the terminal after booting via USB.
4. Updated "systemd" (apt get systemd)
5. Rebooted the computer and was able to login to the main OS in the computer and carry out updates which were broken/not complete.